# Is there a way to calcullate difference between 2 dates (first one and last one) in dax / powerbi?

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

For example i have a have this excel file with the date of stage change of every candidate

[image: Excel Table]

What i'm trying to do is to calculate how many days on average it's taking to a candidate to move from technical test sent to technical test review.
the problem is that sometimes candidates are moved by mistake and the system records both movements.

so what i need is a way to calculate average datediff between firstdate of technical test sent and lastdate of technical test review for every candidate.
Any ideas how? Please help :(

Comment: What is your expected output for the given sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with these 3 measure-

```
min_date_tt_sent = 

CALCULATE(
    MIN(your_table_name[date of change]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[candidate id] = MIN(your_table_name[candidate id])
            && your_table_name[stage] = "Technical Test Sent"
    )
)
```

```
max_date_tt_review = 

CALCULATE(
    MAX(your_table_name[date of change]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[candidate id] = MIN(your_table_name[candidate id])
            && your_table_name[stage] = "Technical Test Review"
    )
)
```

```
date difference = DATEDIFF([min_date_tt_sent],[max_date_tt_review],DAY)
```

**Here is the output from your sample data-**

[image]